# How can I set the screen size of SWF-application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I need to set the size of SWF up to 800x600. But I don't know where can I change this property.

There was an idea to change stage width and height, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your document class, after your imports, but before your class declaration you can add something like this:

```
[SWF(width="800", height="600", backgroundColor="#ffffff", frameRate="30")]
```